# React child chart component doesn't get updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and trying to figure out how props and states are work. I've think of a simple application which uses states and props. It has three buttons for increasing and decreasing numbers. It actually works and updates the numbers. I also wanted to a chart component to see the change of the  numbers. But React doesn't update the chart.

My App.js is;

```
import React from "react"
import ChartComponent from './Chart'


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      count: 12,
      data: [{ count: 12 }, { count: 13 }, { count: 169 }]
    }
    this.linearIncrease = this.linearIncrease.bind(this)
    this.parabolicIncrease = this.parabolicIncrease.bind(this)
    this.parabolicDecrease = this.parabolicDecrease.bind(this)
  }

  linearIncrease() {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      let prevState = previousState.data;
      prevState.push({ count: previousState.count + 1 })
      return {
        count: previousState.count + 1,
        data: prevState
      }
    })
  }

  parabolicIncrease() {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      let prevState = previousState.data;
      prevState.push({ count: previousState.count * previousState.count })
      return {
        count: previousState.count * previousState.count,
        data: prevState
      }
    })
  }

  parabolicDecrease() {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      let prevState = previousState.data;
      prevState.push({ count: Math.sqrt(previousState.count) });
      return {
        count: Math.sqrt(previousState.count),
        data: prevState
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.linearIncrease}>Linear Increase!</button>
        <button onClick={this.parabolicIncrease}>Parabolic Increase</button>
        <button onClick={this.parabolicDecrease}>Parabolic Decrease</button>
        <ChartComponent data={this.state.data}></ChartComponent>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Chart.js file;

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    LineChart, Line
} from 'recharts';


const ChartComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <LineChart width={300} height={100} data={props.data} >
                <Line type='monotone' dataKey='count' stroke='#8884d8' strokeWidth={2} />
            </LineChart>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ChartComponent
```

Comment: I'm not modifying the current state object, I'm assigning it to a new object (**prevState**) then push the new values to **prevState**. Besides React updates header but chart isn't updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though `React` update `count` you are still mutating `this.state.data` using `push`.

React re-render only when the reference to the state changes, If you check `this.state.data === prevState.data` you will get `true` because they are the same object reference. That's why Chart doesn't re-render because React doesn't tell `Chart` that `data` has changed.

It is better to always create a new object and then mutate it like so, Also because objects are mutable in JavaScript you can create them using const, this will still allow you to mutate the object but will not let you reassign a new value to the variable.

```
const prevStateData = [...previousState.data];
```

I would also suggest to create a general function which will take a function as the operation and update and state, this will make the code a lot more readable and simple

```
createOperation(fn) {
  return () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const count = fn(prevState.count);
      return {
        count,
        data: [...prevState.data, { count }]
      };
    });
  };
}
```

Then you can define your functions like so

```
linearIncrease(count) {
  return count + 1;
}

parabolicIncrease(count) {
  return count * count;
}

parabolicDecrease(count) {
  return Math.sqrt(count);
}
```

And using them

```
<button onClick={this.createOperation(this.linearIncrease)}>
  Linear Increase!
</button>
<button onClick={this.createOperation(this.parabolicIncrease)}>
  Parabolic Increase
</button>
<button onClick={this.createOperation(this.parabolicDecrease)}>
  Parabolic Decrease
</button>
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pybck)

Answer (score 2):

I updated the `linearIncrease` logic to make it work:

```
linearIncrease() {
  this.setState(previousState => {
    return {
      // ...previousState,
      count: previousState.count + 1,
      data: [...previousState.data, {count: previousState.count + 1}],
    }
  })
}
```

*The source code under the question updates the count but it doesn't modify data object. React compares the props and it doesn't update the chart component because there is no change to apply. (Chart wouldn't change even if the component was updated because the change is not presented in the data object)*

Here is the working button and the source code: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chart-state

Comment: Maybe an explanation would be better. Also, we don't need to spread `previousState` since React merges the state with the updated properties. Upvoted for the simple solution.

Comment: @devserkan You are right. I commented out the `...previousState` part and added some explaination.